# How to bind new list via Html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, bind, ping

Here is my codes I just want to show on html page. I couldn't understand how to bind it. What do I have to use in HTML page inside foreach and above !DOCTYPE html.Actually I want to check that the IP Address and I want to show if it is online or not via Ping. Thanks for your help.

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private PrinterEntities db = new PrinterEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<string> catlist = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in db.C_Network)
        {
            if (CheckInternetConnection(item.IPAdresi))
            {

                catlist.Add(item.IPAdresi);

            }
        }

        return View(catlist);
    }
    public bool CheckInternetConnection(string HostName)
    {
        bool result = false; // assume error
        try
        {
            Ping oPing = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = oPing.Send(HostName);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
        }
        return result;
    }
}




<div>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @if ()
            {

            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private PrinterEntities db = new PrinterEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<string> catlist = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in db.C_Network)
        {
           if (CheckInternetConnection(item.IPAdresi))
             catlist.Add(item.IPAdresi);
        }
    }
    ViewData["List"] = catlist;
    return View();
}
```

You can get the list in aspx by`List<string> Cats = (List<string>)ViewData["List"];` and iterate in for loop